# Sorting a div content stored in a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anyone please take a look at this and provide me a better solution, so that it will work. I have already banged my head on this and if you could assist me to solve. You will be remembered.

Question: I have a Variable which will hold the below div values in it. I am constructing it dynamically and I want to sort it alphabetically and display it.

```
Var toSort = "<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1571' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Customer Experience Team</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1567' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>1234</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1569' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1266' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1570' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Corporate Communication</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1260' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/>"
```

In the above code, div element Id will be assigned dynamically. Kindly help to solve the problem.

Comment: Sort alphabetically ? How ? Can you show us your desired output.

Comment: Of course I don't know where you got the html from, but the only real solution is to sort before building the html. You are creating a mess this way.

Comment: `I am constructing it dynamically` So this is your point where you need to sort even before concatenating it into a string. So add your div's to a array and then sort it by Id and then concat

Comment: Expected output div should be sorted alpahanumerically (special characters first, numbers, then alphabets).

Comment: @PeterB & Rajshekar Reddy: Yes, I got similar suggestions from some of my known sources. But the thing is that, the code is written for 8000 lines by someone who is not here. So I just want to know, whether we can do it without touching the constructing part & handle it at the last.

Comment: if this is a temporary workaround, then i guess it will be easier to sort the DOM when built than to parse the string

Comment: Check the answer i have posted. It will be very helpful for you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone, all the 3 were helpful. I preferred the one with the "localecompare", since it involves minimal code change. #AppreciateyourhelpingMinds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would use an Array for it and also create an element first with jquery so its easier to get access to it.

Than you can easily sort it with "localecompare"

```js
var yourElements = [];

yourElements.push( $("<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1571' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Customer Experience Team</div></div>")[0]);
yourElements.push($("<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1567' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>1234</div></div>")[0]);
yourElements.push($("<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1569' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div>")[0]);
yourElements.push( $("<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1266' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div>")[0]);
yourElements.push( $("<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1570' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Corporate Communication</div></div>")[0]);

yourElements.sort(function(a,b)
{

 return a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText);

});

console.log(yourElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just copy in browser and test it you cant expand the object from the snipped

Answer (score 0):

Do mean sorting by id like this?

```js
toSort = "<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1571' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Customer Experience Team</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1567' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>1234</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1569' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1266' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1570' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Corporate Communication</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1260' style='background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/>";

a = toSort.split("<br/>");
obj = {}
for(key in a){
 id = a[key].substr(53,4);
  obj[id] = a[key];
}
newhtml = "";
for(key in obj){
 newhtml += obj[key]+"<br/>";
}
console.log(newhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the perfect way to achieve the sort you require. Although there are few answers already posted. I would like you to check this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var toSort = "<div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1571' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Customer Experience Team</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1567' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>1234</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1569' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1266' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1570' style = 'background:#b7b7b7;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Corporate Communication</div></div><br/><div class='touchpoint_filterattributes' id='BODIVID_1260' style = 'background:#C9C9C9;'><div class='color_box_label' style = 'color:#000000;'>Claims</div></div><br/>",

 i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, divs;
 $('#container').append(toSort);

 
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    //Loop through all divs items:
    divs = $('.touchpoint_filterattributes');
    for (i = 0; i < (divs.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item:*/
      if ($(divs[i]).find('.color_box_label').text().toLowerCase() > $(divs[i+1]).find('.color_box_label').text().toLowerCase()) {
        /*if next item is alphabetically lower than current item,
        mark as a switch and break the loop:*/
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done:*/
      divs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divs[i + 1], divs[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
   $('#container').append(divs);

});
```

```css
.touchpoint_filterattributes{margin:20px 0px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```